# Invalid block tag on line 4: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django

I am getting an error Invalid block tag on line : 'endblock. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Home
{% endblock %} 

{% block content %}
<h1>Home Page</h1>
{% endblock %} #This is tag that the error is referring to
```

This is my base.html in which it inherits from

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>{% block title %} My Site {% endblock %}</title>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <div id="content" , name="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

For more context here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ToDoList, Item

# Create your views here.

def index(response, id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(response, "main/base.html", {})

def home(response):
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {})
```

and urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:id>", views.index, name="index"),
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
]
```

Comment: it works when just copy pasting you code. Try to copy past from your post and the error will be fixed.

Comment: @Tanner Ormanoski after div id="content" there should not be a comma (although my code works with it). Show your urls.py and view.

Comment: @inquirer I have edited to add the additional files.

Comment: @akun.dev I did and still not working. It is strange, I can not see what is visibly wrong and it seems to be working when ya'll are using the code.

Comment: @TannerOrmanoski which view is getting the error, also show the call url(internet address)?

Comment: @inquirer the error is coming from the home view at 127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: @TannerOrmanoski did you manage to display the template from the main application (any template) at all? I have an assumption that the program simply does not see your templates. Both views work for me.

Comment: @inquirer I was able to display the home when I had one content block, and then when I added a second one for the title I got the mentioned error. I went ahead and turned off my text editor which was "Prettier" as it was formatting my home.html file in an unpleasant to read way and retyped the file and blocks and it worked strangely.

Comment: @inquirer I am not sure why formatting would effect it, because I have used "prettier" in a flask app before and created templates in the same way, and did not receive an error, and I am 99% sure it was not a syntax error as you were able to use my code, but it works now.